# When I run my Django project developed on Windows on Ubuntu it gives errors as below, even after creating virtualenv and configured properly

Tags: python, html, css, django, python-3.9

Here is the errors

I have installed and created virtualenv as same like the one on Windows and replaced it on Ubuntu with that new one. I could activate the virtual but when I do python3 manage.py runserver it gives error as like below. If someone help, it will be grateful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 105, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 602, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pema/Desktop/Django/devsearch/devsearch/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    path("", include("users.urls"))
  File "/home/pema/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pema/Desktop/Django/devsearch/users/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from. import views
  File "/home/pema/Desktop/Django/devsearch/users/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, ProfileForm, SkillForm
  File "/home/pema/Desktop/Django/devsearch/users/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataclasses import fields
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
```

Answer (score 0):

Data classes were introduced in Python 3.7. You are running Python 3.6.

Comment: Then how can I correct it Jim please...

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3.7 or greater.

Comment: Thank you Jim. Appreciate for you time and helps. Always thankful Jim.